# How to get the attribute value in the SAX parser

Tags: sax, saxparser

I have use the SAXParser to read the xml format. Then the startelement method run but I have no idea how to get the url in the method. I dont know what is the solution. Thank you

```
<enclosure length="1234567" type="image/jpeg" url="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/664322main_31_lands_cropped_516-387.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**What language? What implementation?** It is always a good idea to at least tag which language you are trying to implement in.

The idea is to iterate through the attributes parameter in the startElement() function/method:

A Java solution:

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
{
   int len = atts.getLength();
   // Loop through all attributes and save them as needed
   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      String sAttrName = atts.getLocalName(i);
      if(sAttrName.compareTo("URL") == 0) 
      {
          String sVal = atts.getValue(i);
          // Do something with the *.jpg
      }
   }
}
```

A C++ [Xercesc](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDefaultHandler.html#931f1eac710f7d81d2714c78a4c8cb60) solution:

```
void MyClass::startElement(const XMLCh *const uri, const XMLCh *const localname,
                                  const XMLCh *const qname, const Attributes &attributes)
{
    // Loop through all attributes and save them as needed
    XMLSize_t len = attributes.getLength();
    for(XMLSize_t index = 0; index < len; index++)
    {
         CString cAttrName(attributes.getLocalName(index));
         if(cAttrName.Compare(L"URL") == 0)
         {
              CString cVal(attributes.getValue(index));
              // Do something with the *.jpg
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The attributes are passed into the startElement method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
    String attributeName = attrs.getLocalName(i);
    String attributeValue = attrs.getValue(i);
    System.out.println("found attribute with localname=" + attributeName 
    + " and value=" + attributeValue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my attempt at the [SAX ContentHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html); it returns attributes and key / value pairs.

```
private String mCurrentEl = null;

/** on each element: start */
public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

    /** keeping a reference */
    mCurrentEl = localName;

    /** each attribute */
    for (int i=0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
        String name  = attrs.getLocalName(i);
        String value = attrs.getValue(i);
        System.out.println("attribute \"" + name + "\" has value \"" + value + "\".");
   }

}

/** on each element: data */
public void characters(char[] chars, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    String data = new String(chars, start, length).trim();
    if(! data.equals("") && mCurrentEl != null) {
        System.out.println(mCurrentEl + ": " + data);
    }
}

/** on each element: end */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    mCurrentEl = null;
}
```