# Difference among XML SAX parser, Pull parser & DOM Parser in android

Tags: android, saxparser, xmlpullparser, domparser

I want to know what's the difference between XML **SAX parser, Pull parser & DOM parser** in Android. In which condition, which one is better in performance and implementation?

Thanx.
Khobaib.

Answer (score 34):

**Dom Parser -**  It uses ***object based*** approach. i.e., it first loads the entire XML in memory, converts the XML nodes into objects and then starts parsing them. So, it is pretty slower.

**SAX and PULL Parser -** they use ***event based*** approach. Both are almost same in terms of memory and performance. However there are few distinguishing situations on when to use them as described below.

**Dom Parser -** Use it when you need to ***validate*** the entire XML before parsing.
Never use it when the XML is too large and validation can be compromised.
Once it starts parsing, it parses from starting node to ending node. there is no way to parse only particular nodes.

**SAX -** Use it when you want to parse the entire XML.
Once it starts parsing, it parses from starting node to ending node. there is no way to parse only particular nodes.

**PULL -** Use it when you don't want to parse the entire XML. It is easier to implement than SAX, because you don't have to maintain the state of your parser. You can pull only a particular node you are interested at.

My suggestion is - Need ***validation - Go for DOM***, File size is ***small*** or you are not interested in parsing of entire XML- Go for ***PULL***, File size is ***large*** or you need to parse the ***entire XML*** file - Go for ***SAX***.

Comment: SAX has issue with self close tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707531/trouble-parsing-self-closing-xml-tags-using-sax-parser

Answer (score 14):

**Sax Parser :** Simple API of XML
           Parse node to node, using top-down traversing, parse without storing xml, 
           Faster compared to Dom
           Manipulating of node like insertion or deletion is allowed.
       Needs SAXParserFactory

**Dom Parser :** Document Object Model
             Stores entire xml in memory before processing, traverse in any direction,
             Manipulating of node like insertion or deletion is NOT allowed.
         Needs DocumentBuilderFactory

**Pull Parser:** It provides more control and speed from the above two. Needs pullParserFactory

Comment: Isn't it contrarily with Sax and DOM? Dom does allow insertion and deletion while Sax is only a parser? Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

Comment: Hey, admins, please edit the answer (because this one has the most votes) according to above comment: DOM **allows** nodes inserting/deleting, while SAX **doesn't**

Comment: How come Sax is faster than Pull ? For Pull, you can even stop parsing while reading, so it means you can do less work if needed...

Answer (score 0):

As far as performance, SAX will generally use much less memory. And you only handle the events you want, e.g. startElement(), startDocument(), endElement(), etc. etc., and thus you will only save specific data you want. DOM will load the entire XML file into memory.